# Is there a way to check if android WindowManager already contains a view?

Tags: android, android-layout

When I try to do a WindowManager.removeView(),

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 2445): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=android.widget.LinearLayout{41a03700 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0} not attached to window manager

E/AndroidRuntime( 2445):             at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:370)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2445):             at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)

E/AndroidRuntime( 2445):             at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:79)
```

I get this fatal error because the view was not in the window manager.
Is there no way to check if windowmanager had already added the view before?
I do not see any such method in the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/211370fd943cf26905001b38b8b1791851b26adc/core/java/android/view/WindowManagerImpl.java)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can check to see if the view's window token is null:

```
if(view.getWindowToken() != null){
    WindowManager.removeView(view);
}
```

You could also just catch the exception:

```
try{
    WindowManager.removeView(view);
}catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
    Log.e(debug_tag, "view not found");
}
```

Comment: I can try your suggestion, but it doesn't seem 'right'. An exception IMHO should not be ignored - when there is a bug in my program, ignoring the exception will be bad.

Comment: I agree, you should not ignore it, but it is a potential workaround. I've added another idea.

Comment: doing the try-catch and ignoring it, worked... let me try your other idea. Is it robust? never heard of window token.

Comment: I'm not sure of its robustness, I have never used it myself either. I just found it in the source. Perhaps the best solution is a combination of the two?

Comment: for some reason, getWindowToken() did not work. I switched back to catching and ignoring the exception. Thanks. I was considering adding a method containsView() to the android AOSP WindowManager, but it will likely be rejected - argued as unnecessary.

Comment: You may also be able to leverage view.isShown()

Comment: what if you don't have a reference to the view instance (if you want to control visibility from different services/activities)? can we check it somehow with View ID (`@id/root_view_floating_id`)?

Answer (score 8):

Its also a better way to check its already added on window or not.

```
if (view.getParent() != null)) {
    windowsManager.removeView(view);
}
```