# View has already been added to the window manager

Tags: android

I have a view, which I add to the window manager. Before adding I check if it has already been added to the window manager, like in another questions on stackoverflow:

```
protected void addViewToWindow(@NonNull OverlayLayout view) {
    if (view.getWindowToken() == null) {
        handler.post(() -> windowManager.addView(view, view.getViewParams()));
    }
}
```

But on some devices with Android 5 there is this exception:

```
View has already been added to the window manager.
       at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:243)
       at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

How can I fix this? Help me please

Comment: It seems you are calling `addViewToWindow` with a view that the system later tried to attach to a window manager. Can you edit your question to explain where you call the method?

Comment: Note:- Why you checking null again using if conditions you already checking with this notations @NonNull.

Comment: @HeikkiMäenpää I only need to check if this view already attached or not

Comment: @sushildlh NonNull for view not for window token

Comment: Put a `Log` at the end of your method to see if your code or the system (as @HeikkiMäenpää is implying) is causing the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if android WindowManager already contains a view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044024/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-android-windowmanager-already-contains-a-view)

Comment: @sushildlh It seems that this question already contains the solution in that answer (except for the bit mentioned in my answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking whether the view is attached to window before calling `handler.post` to attach it later. The view ends up getting attached between your check and when the `Looper` processes your callback. You should move the check `if (view.getWindowToken() == null)` into the callback you pass to `post`, so this check happens immediately before you attempt to attach the view to a window.